# Equilibrium in lattice simulations

Tags: lattice-model

It will be very kind of you if i am informed if there is any flaw in my understanding, or if there is any advice for my idea. It is said that one has to keep updating until the lattice can produce a distribution which gives a certain quantity irrespective of the starting history on lattice (for example, by comparing cold and hot starts as some authors put it). My idea is the following:

We start with two randomly selected configurations for separate runs. But instead of updating and sweeping, we just keep on calculating the one point function while considering all the points on Markov chain. When the one point functions from the two runs agree with each other, we announce that we have reached an equilibrium.

Is there something wrong with this idea? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to say. Is the general idea to use time averaged quantities rather than spaially averaged ones? Also what sort of system do you have in mind here?

Comment: The thought i had is the following: I collect the first N decorrelated configurations and calculate a one point function from them. Then i do the same but with a different starting configuration. Then i compare the two one point functions. At the value of N, when the two one point functions agree within statistical fluctuations, i declare that it is the moment when equilibrium has established. Is there anything wrong with this idea?

Comment: And these one point functions are to be spatially averaged, hence if i plot them they will be plotted against time points since they are averaged over space points.